# Homework policy

Tags: discussion, questions

Although this issue more than likely won't be as much of an issue as say, Physics.SE and Mathematics.SE, there could still be astronomy-based homework questions.  I think we need to hash out a homework question policy, just in case.

I am not really keen on a [homework](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag at all, as questions should be about specific astronomy topics.

- homework of this topic would usually be a school project, or university student questions.

What do other think?

Answer (score 8):

My opinion on the subject is that

1. We probably won't have a huge amount of homework questions,
2. We should accept the questions *as long as they follow our other rules*.

For example, *following our other rules* would mean:

- '*why does the universe has stuff in it*' would be closed as too broad.
- '*For a planet with as much mass as foo has, why does it do x?*' would be perfectly fine.

Basically, we shouldn't really even care about whether the question is homework or not. If it's a good question, it's a good question. If it's too broad, it's too broad. That's my opinion on the matter.

Comment: So, you agree - no [tag:homework] tag

Comment: We probably don't *need* it, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Although I agree a homework tag is not necessary, I'm surprised it hasn't been debated more here.

The main argument for having a homework tag, I think, is it would allow people to avoid or seek out those questions more easily (depending on their personal preference).

It also might make it easier to search for if the problem has already been asked.

"I am not really keen on a homework tag at all, as questions should be about specific astronomy topics."

I agree that a question should be specific and related to astronomy but couldn't we just make the homework tag not stand alone (meaning, someone would need to include another tag as well as the homework tag)?

Comment: It looks like we have about 10 homework questions (that are openly acknowledged as such--if they aren't acknowledged, it's not worth trying to force the tag on the OP), so it may be worth revisiting this discussion.